# Cannot implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'system.collections.generic.list <int>?

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I am receiving the error

> cannot implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'system.collections.generic.list ?

Could anyone help me on this?

```
internal class PatchDetails
{
    internal List<int> ServerID { get; set; }
    internal List<string> PatchStatus { get; set; }
}
class Program
{        
    void PatchQueue()
    {
        List<PatchDetails> patchinfo = new List<PatchDetails>();            
        using (PatchEntities server = new PatchEntities())
        {
            patchinfo = (from patches in server.AppPM_Patches
                         where patches.PatchStatus == "Started" 
                         || patches.PatchStatus == "NotStarted"
                         select new PatchDetails { ServerID = patches.ServerId, PatchStatus = patches.PatchStatus }).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: PatchStatus must be both 'Started' and 'NotStarted'?

Comment: sorry. i changed the code.now check

Comment: Note: You don't need to create a list when you declare the variable, as you create another list to assign to it. Just declare the variable: `List<PatchDetails> patchinfo;`

Answer (score 2):

You are putting a `int` and a `string` in the object, so I think that you want each `PatchDetails` to contain those, not lists of them:

```
internal class PatchDetails
{
  internal int? ServerID { get; set; }
  internal string PatchStatus { get; set; }
}
```

If you don't want the `ServerID` property to be nullable, then get the value from the `int?` in the query:

```
ServerID = patches.ServerId.Value
```

Comment: No. i want a list of all ServerID and Patch Status

Comment: @Karthi: You already have a list. If the class contains lists, then you get a list of lists of details instead of a list of details.

Answer (score 0):

The select statement returns a single PatchDetails object, your trying to cast a single class to a list which is incorrect.

If your trying to get a single object u could remove .ToList().